# SQLdatabse error no such column _id?

Tags: android

```
07-10 21:24:23.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(389): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fttech.taskask/com.fttech.taskask.TaskList}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id: , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, descrip, date, time, type
```

Is the error i keep getting with this code. I dont know what is causing it. because i have everything corrent.
Here is my code i use

```
class TaskHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "windowShopper";
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;

public TaskHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE task (_id   INTEGER   PRIMARY   KEY    AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, descrip TEXT, date TEXT, time TEXT, type TEXT)");


}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public Cursor getAll(){
    return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, title, descrip, date, time, type", null));

}
public void insert(String title, String descrip, String date, String time, String status){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("title", title);
    cv.put("descrip", descrip);
    cv.put("date", date);
    cv.put("time", time);
    cv.put("status", status);
    getWritableDatabase().insert("task", "name", cv);
}
public Cursor getById(String id){
    String [] args = {id};

    return(getReadableDatabase()    
            .rawQuery("SELECT _id, title, descrip, date, time, status FROM task WHERE _ID=?",args));


}
public void update(String id, String title, String descrip, String date, String time, String type){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    String [] args={id};
    cv.put("title", title);
    cv.put("descrip", descrip);
    cv.put("date", date);
    cv.put("time", time);
    cv.put("status", type);
    getWritableDatabase().update("task", cv, "_ID=?", args);


}
public String getTitle(Cursor c){
    return(c.getString(2));
}
public String getDescrip(Cursor c){
    return(c.getString(3));
}
public String getDate(Cursor c){
    return(c.getString(4));

}
public String getTime(Cursor c){
    return(c.getString(5));
}
public String getStatus(Cursor c){
    return(c.getString(6));
}
```

}

```
07-10 21:34:27.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(428): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id: , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, descrip, date, time, type
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to wrap _id in quotes like this "_id"

---

After seeing your comment the escaping was not the problem as you said, it was the missing FROM clause

Comment: I tried, i posted the error i get at the bottom of the question. check it out

Comment: in my getAll method i forgot to tell it WHERE. Wow. careless error

Comment: Are you sure? The WHERE clause is optional and show not cause problems if absent.

Comment: Oh, you mean you forgot the FROM clause